# How to convert an angle vector to Euclidean coordinates given a fixed amplitude, in n dimension

Tags: python, math, wolfram-mathematica

so to convert a polar coordinate (amplitude, angle) to euclidean coordinates in 2D is straight forward.

But in n (say n = 5) dimension, I have a fixed amplitude, and a randomised angle vector. How can I convert it into an euclidean vector of the coordinates?

```
amp = 0.5
n = 5
ang = np.random.rand(n) * 2* pi
```

Many thanks

Comment: As the answer so far shows, the amplitude and one angle are not enough to specify a vector in dimensions greater than two. In 5 dimensions, will you be given the amplitude and four (randomized) angles, or something else? And do you want the probability distribution of the resulting angles to be uniform over the n-dimensional sphere with the given amplitude? The answer so far does *not* accomplish this, as good as it is otherwise.

Comment: do you just want a random vector, or do you want to convert a given vector (as the title says).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2D, the conversion is:

```
x = amp * cos(angle)
y = amp * sin(angle)
```

In 3D, one option is:

```
x = amp * cos(angle1) * cos(angle2)
y = amp * sin(angle1) * cos(angle2)
z = amp *               sin(angle2)
```

You should see a pattern. The dimensions that already exist get a factor of `cos(newAngle)`. The new dimension gets `sin(newAngle)`. So, in 4D, this would be:

```
x = amp * cos(angle1) * cos(angle2) * cos(angle3)
y = amp * sin(angle1) * cos(angle2) * cos(angle3)
z = amp *               sin(angle2) * cos(angle3)
w = amp *                             sin(angle3)
```

In general, the `i`-th dimension is (1-based):

```
dim_i = sin(angle_(i-1)) * Product {j from i to n} cos(angle_j)
```

(Only if `angle_(i-1)` exists, otherwise set the term to `1`).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.